# Include Column name in SQL Unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have an unnormalized data set I need to normalize for reporting purposes.

```
    SELECT [Id]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[Question1]
      ,[Question2]
      ,[Question3]
      ,[Question4]
  FROM [COS].[dbo].[Sheet2$]
```

[image]

I successfully unpivoted the data using this:

```
    SELECT Id,
       Result
FROM   (SELECT Id,
               Cast([Question1] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Q1,
               Cast([Question2] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Q2,
               Cast([Question3] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Q3,
               Cast([Question4] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Q4
        FROM   Sheet2$) AS A
       UNPIVOT ( result
               FOR questions IN ( Q1,
                                  Q2,
                                  Q3,
                                  Q4 ) ) AS b
```

[image]

How can unpivot column headers Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4 as a third column in my unpivot query, like this?

[image]

Comment: When you write `unpivot( measure for label in (<column_list>))` you'll get two columns: `measure` will hold the values (row-wise) which were in columns `<column_list>` and `label` will hold the name of the corresponding column from the `<column_list>`. So you just need to add `questions` column in select list.

Comment: But anyway, please provide source data, your current and desired output [in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557). You can use [ASCII table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) for this.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks like SQL Server.  If so, just use a `APPLY`:

```
SELECT s.id, v.*
FROM Sheet2$ s CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('Question1', s.Question1),
             ('Question2', s.Question2),
             ('Question3', s.Question3),
             ('Question4', s.Question4)
     ) v(question, result);
```